# how do I pass output from cli-php to bat-file

Tags: batch-file

how can I pass output (from cli-php) to a bat file argument, example:

```
@echo off
php myScript.php > %%1
rmdir /S /Q %%1
```

I know I may delete the file using php only.

regards,

//t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you capture the output of any command into a variable:
`FOR /F %%A IN ('command') DO ...`

You need to set the appropriate FOR /F options to parse/preserve the value(s) you want. In this case you will likely want `"DELIMS="` in case the path contains spaces.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('php myScript.php') do rmdir /s /q "%%~A"
```

I suppose it is possible for the path to begin with a semicolon, which would cause the FOR /F to ignore the output due to default `"EOL=;"`. A path can't begin with a colon, so you could set `"EOL=:"` just to be safe:

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ('php myScript.php') do rmdir /s /q "%%~A"
```